# Justice League: Team Composition

Tags: dc, green-lantern, justice-league, justice-league-2017

According to the story line in the new Justice league movie, why wasn't **[Green Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hal_Jordan)** included in the character list?

As per wiki, the original creation of the Justice League comprised of 7 founding members. How come they chose not to include Hal Jordan?

[image]

It's pretty understandable that they chose not to show J’onn J’onzz, a.k.a [Martian Manhunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_Manhunter), as most people who has no knowledge about DC or the JL wouldn't know who the strange, green martian is. Also for the fact that he wasn't a part of the original 7, but was the first inductee into the established JL. But as for Hal Jordan, we already saw a movie (although, an awful one) about the Green Lantern.

Is there any reason that you know of, why the will-powered powerhouse was excluded from the movie?

Comment: Maybe that "awful" adjective is a clue? ;)

Comment: @ibid I wasn't aware of the fact that this was asked earlier. Sorry about that. And thank you for reverting me to it. Cheers.

Comment: @VarunNair - If you couldn't find the other question before asking yours, chances are others may not be able to either. Duplicates serve [as signposts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) to help future users find the answer.

Comment: As ibid said, it’s not an issue that you asked it again, if anything it helps cast the net wider so more people will see both your answer and the linked duplicate! If anything it’s evidence it’s a good question given the originals score.

Comment: Thanks for your time, guys. Much appreciated.